# Insert a symbol before and after a number in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to add a character before and after a number in Notepad++?

Right now I have:

Awareness 200 Skill —

What I would like is:

Awareness |200| Skill —

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reg expression in the find/replace dialogue (it is the last option in the find/replace dialogue box under search mode). In your case u can use search with

`([0-9]*)`

Make sure to put space after bracket end.  In Replace put

```
|\1|
```

"|" can be replaced with any other symbol of ur choice. \1 is nothing but argument so should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+F -> *replace Awareness 200 Skill* by *Awareness |200| Skill*

You can also do it in multiple files